# Launch mac finder window with specified path

Tags: r, rgui

Is there a way to launch a mac finder window from the RGUI command line? I'm going through a bunch of files and it would be helpful to see the folder instead of having to use list.files()

Comment: Are you looking to open up a dialog box for choosing files for input, or just open up a Finder window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open up the Finder from the RGUI command line, the direct solution is to use:

```
system("open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/")
```

EDIT: For a specified path, `system("open ~/Desktop")` would open the Finder at the user's desktop, for example, because in MacOSX the default application to open any directory is the Finder.

Comment: is there a way to specify the path to open in the finder window?

Comment: @JoshDG: I've edited my answer to specify the path in the Finder window.

Answer (score 1):

To select (and return to R) files using Mac's the native file selection dialog can be done as follows, though this solution relies on `qtbase` and the Qt libraries:

```
library(qtbase)
file_selector <- function(initial_dir=getwd(), multiple=FALSE) {
  f <- Qt$QFileDialog()
  ## configure
  f$setDirectory(initial_dir)
  if(multiple)
    f$setFileMode(Qt$QFileDialog$ExistingFiles)
  ## run
  out <- f$exec()
  if(out == 1)
    f$selectedFiles()
  else
    NULL
}
```

If you install the aqua tk libraries (not the X11 ones) then likely `tkgetOpenFile` could be used, though I didn't check.